# how to replace a line with backtick Ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

How can I comment the below line using ansible

```
dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
```

The result should be

```
#dnl FEATURE(`relay_based_on_MX')dnl
```

I tried using `lineinfile`, replace, regexp but did not work

Comment: Ist that line in a file? Are there other lines?

Comment: there are other lines also.  but i need to  find and comment only this line

Comment: Please ban the phrase "but no luck" from your vocabulary when asking for help. What **did** it do, and where is the code for your attempt, because the details matter a great deal. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: comment out line in file
    replace:
      path: /home/me/testfile.txt
      regexp: "^dnl FEATURE"
      replace: "#dnl FEATURE"
```